# How to upload and view images in django

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
 class FileUpload(models.Model):
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    File_path = models.FileField(upload_to='')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Upload_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
 class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
   class Meta:
      model = FileUpload

      File_Name = forms.CharField(label="File Name",max_length=255)  
      Description = forms.CharField(label="Description", max_length=255)
```

I'm new in Django.I  need help. How to upload images in the database and view those images? Thanks in advance!

here paths are stored in database and images are stored in a folder. But I don't need that. I want to save images and path to the database and I need to view that image. Please help!

views.py:

```
def uploadfile(request):
   print('inside upload logic')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
        # ImageUpload(request.FILES['File_Name'])  
         myfile = request.FILES['File_Name']

         fs = FileSystemStorage()
         filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
         uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
         newdoc = FileUpload(File_Name=myfile.name, File_path=uploaded_file_url,  Description=request.POST['Description'])
         newdoc.save()
         #return HttpResponse("File uploaded successfuly")  
         return render(request, 'Login/fileupload.html')   
   else:
      form = FileUploadForm()
      return render(request, 'Login/fileupload.html', {
      'form': form
   })
```

Comment: what error are you facing, and kindly upload forms.py code

Comment: Please upload your forms.py and models.py code

Comment: Why do you need to upload images to the database?

Comment: "project I'm working on demands it" is not an answer a serious developer should take for granted. It almost never makes sense to save images directly into a database (99% of the time). It's much slower to access images from a database than from a file system. Databases are not made for storing and retrieving large blobs of data. Are you sure you need to save the image to database?

Comment: I  need to upload  and view that images.

Comment: But uploading and viewing the image doesn't mean storing the image to the database. It means storing a `ImageField` in your database (which references the image on disk). [This doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) shows exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You normally shouldn't store the image data in your database. If you need to upload and store images, use the `ImageField` or `FileField` and follow the instructions from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) to save the image. The only thing you need to do is:

```
form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    uploaded_file = FileUpload(
        File_path=request.FILES['File_path'],  # or whatever you've called the file input
        File_name=form.cleaned_data['File_Name'],
        Description=form.cleaned_data['Description'])
    uploaded_file.save()
```

It would be easier to use a `ModelForm` in your case, then you only need to save the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

This will automatically save the file in the correct way. No need to do the saving manually like you are doing.

To view the image is as simple as this:

```
file_upload = FileUpload.objects.get(id=34)
file_url = file_upload.File_path.url  # url relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`

# or in a template
{% load static %}
{% get_media_prefix %}{{ file_upload.File_path.url }}
```

If you really need to store the images as binary blobs to your database (but beware that it almost never makes sense to do so), use Django's `BinaryField`, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).

This also means you will have to handle transforming the image back and forth from a binary blob to a proper image file. Consider also storing the content type (image/jpg or image/png or image/webp) since you will need that to properly re-create the file.